# Save binary image to SQL-CE in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-ce

I have an SQL-CE table called Recipe, within this table there are 4 columns ID(int), Name(nvarchar), Instructions(nvarchar) and image(binary).

This is what the UI looks like:

[image]

When you click on the 'Add New' button I want the user to input a Name, Instructions and then click the AddImage button and select an image. I then want the label containing the text 'No image in memory' to change to 'Image in memory' To signify that an image is waiting to be written to the database. Finally when the user clicks the Save icon, I want the 3 nvarchar fields to be saved, as well as the image written to the table as a binary.

Here is the code:

**Add Image button**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int size = -1;
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
            if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
            {
                string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                try
                {
                    string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
                    size = text.Length;
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                }
            }


        }
```

**Save Icon**

```
 private void recipeBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.recipeBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.recipeDataSet);
            MessageBox.Show("Recipe Saved!", "Save Item");

        }
```

Finally I would like each corresponding image saved in the db to be displayed below the Add Image button in a picture box, so it will need to be converted back from binary format to display the image.

**My Question**

How do I change the **'No image in memory'** label to display **'Image in memory'** once a file has been selected by bringing up the **OpenFileDialog** screen. And then what code do I need to add to make the save button click event write the image to my SQL-CE db as a binary file.

Comment: @Otiel Sorry, I have summarised what I need to accomplish at the bottom now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the file, you can read it into an array of bytes, then copy the array to the correct filed in the current record

Something along the lines of

OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

```
// if the user selects a file
if(openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // now open the file ..
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    // or you may use 
    // FileStream fs = (FileStream)openFileDialog.OpenFile();

    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    Byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
    br.Close();
    fs.Close();
}

// now copy content of 'buffer' to the correct filed of the recordset
```

**To change the label**, you should be able to check whether the above filed has a value when you navigate through your recordset by subscribing to the correct BindingSource event  (***CurrentItemChanged*** if my memory serves me right)

Comment: what would go in the place of yourFilePath? The user will be selecting the file from their local machine using the openfiledialog so I would expect the file path to be autp populated?

Comment: You are correct.. replace yourFilePath with path+fileName collected via OpenFileDialog - cm

Comment: Apologies but what would the code be for this as I have not used OpenFileDialog before. Thanks

Comment: Hi SelectDistinct, I modified the code for you.. have a go @it.. please note that I didnt have a VS while doing the modification so you will have to check for the accuracy of the syntax. A good reference about OpenFileDialog http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.openfile(v=vs.71).aspx - hope this will help you .. happy coding